# Geckoboard with Django 1.7

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-1.7, geckoboard

I have installed django-geckoboard using `easy_install django-geckoboard`
and i am creating a custom widget to count comment (number_widget) but is displaying import error `cannot import name simplejson`

I am attaching the code.

```
from datetime import date, time, datetime
from django.contrib.comments.models import Comment
from django_geckoboard.decorators import number_widget


@number_widget(format='xml')
def comment_count(request):
    midnight = datatime.combine(date.today(), time.min)
    return Comment.objects.filter(submit_data__get=midnight).count()`
```

Comment: what is the solution for this

Comment: This issue is solved.I have removed the simplejson and django-geckoboard package and then again installed it from scratch.